# What's the Best Way to Apply Numbering to a Jquery Sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

After trying out a number of methods, I have searched high and low for a good solution to a seemingly easy problem.

I have a sortable list of chapters and I'm using averaging to make jquery sortable work for a meteor application. The dragging and dropping sortable part is easy (using averaging), but applying the correct (whole number) order of the chapters has been tricky.

A common application would be chapter numbers applied to a table of contents.

What I've tried:

1. Rewriting the stop: function using a for loop that accounts for the different scenarios. Drag to front, drag to rear

This can get complex as the numbers of chapters increase. I felt it was too complex a solution.

2. Using jQuery to identify the order of the items and apply the numbers according to their sorted order in the browser. I think this will work, but I haven't been able to figure out what jquery functions to use and where after trying several out. Disclaimer: I'm new to Spacebars and haven't used much jquery.

chaptersList html:

```
<template name="chaptersList">
  <div id="items">              
   {{#each publishedChapters}}
      {{> chapterItem}}
   {{/each}}
 </div><!--items-->
</template>
```

chaptersList js:

```
    Template.chaptersList.rendered = function() {
      this.$('#items').sortable({
        stop: function(e, ui) {
          // get the dragged html element and the one before
          //   and after it
          el = ui.item.get(0)
          before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
          after = ui.item.next().get(0)

          if(!before) {
            //if it was dragged into the first position grab the
            // next element's data context and subtract one from the order
            newOrder = 1;
          } else if(!after) {
            //if it was dragged into the last position grab the
            //  previous element's data context and add one to the order
            newOrder = Blaze.getData(before).order + 1
          }
          else
            //else take the average of the two orders of the previous
            // and next elements
            newOrder = (Blaze.getData(after).order +
                       Blaze.getData(before).order)/2

            newOrder = Math.round(newOrder)

          //update the Items' orders
          Chapters.update({_id: Blaze.getData(el)._id}, {$set: {order: newOrder}})
        }
      })
    }

    Template.chaptersList.helpers({

      publishedChapters: function() { 
                           return Chapters.find({ published: true }, 
                           { sort: {order: 1} 
                         }); 
      },

      items: function() { 
             return Chapters.find({}, { 
                   sort: {order: 1 } 
             }) 
       }
    });
```

chapterItem html:

```
    <template name="chapterItem">

            <div class="item">

                <h3 class="headroom-10 chapter-title-small">
                  <a href="{{pathFor 'showChapter'}}">{{title}}</a>
                </h3>
                <p class="chapter-text">{{#markdown}}{{chapterTease}}{{/markdown}}</p>

                {{#if ownChapter}}
                  <a href="{{pathFor 'editChapter'}}" class="chapter-text">Edit</a>
                  <span class="delete">
                      <a href="#">Delete</a>
                  </span>
                {{/if}}
            </div>

    </template>
```

Thank you for your valuable insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this same issue and the trick to get it working cleanly in my case was to cancel the sortable action from inside the sort and let Blaze take over once the item was dropped. Otherwise the sortable ordering and Blaze ordering end up wrestling one another.

I save my new set of ordered items as a single batch, but that's not necessarily required.

```
Template.builder.rendered = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.$("ol.sortable").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "ol.sortable",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    update: function(event, ui){
      var
        items = $(this).find("li"),
        picks = _.map(items, function(item){
          var obj = Blaze.getData(item);
          obj.position = $(item).index() + 1;
          return obj;
        });

      self.$('ol.sortable').sortable('cancel');

      Meteor.call(
        "orderPicks",
        team,
        picks,
        function(error, result){}
      );
    }
  });
}
```

And on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  orderPicks: function(team, picks){
    Teams.update(team,
      { $set: {picks: picks} }
    );
    return true;
  }
});
```

I believe I picked this up from another SO thread; I can't remember. In any case it works seamlessly for a modestly sized set of items.

HTML:

```
<template name="builder">
  <ol class="builder sortable">
    {{#each team.picks}}
      <li>{{position}}. {{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting @jeremy. Can you add the html, so I can make sure I'm making the right changes and to resolve the issue?

Comment: Also, re you using `meteor add mrt:jquery-ui `? I'm not able to drag the li items after having applied your suggestion

Comment: I've added a bit of HTML to my answer. For the jqueryui package you may want to try mizzao:jquery-ui as the mrt version is no longer being maintained. However, I'm not sure if the package is the source of the problem if the sortable was working until you tried my suggestion. Note that one difference in my example and yours is that I'm using a nested array on one collection document, not a cursor, so you would need to modify for that behavior.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I think your option is a good one, but I'm going to have to study it in order to apply it correctly. I updated to the new jquery ui package, thanks. For now, I'm going to use an ordered list to number the chapters, which actually works pretty well with the exception of when the items are being dragged, the list numbers try to guess where they are in the list.

Comment: Sounds good, good luck with it! You may also be able to use sortable's 'helper' option to remove/disguise the item number on the item while sorting to make it look a bit cleaner - http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper

Comment: Hi @jeremy, thanks again for your help. I have studied your solution and I like how elegant and concise it is. I have a solution I need to write for multiple documents, but I have one question for you. In your code `update: function(event, ui){
      var
        items = $(this).find("li"),` the `var` is kind of hanging out there and that's something I haven't seen before. What is the purpose of `var` in this example?

Comment: I am declaring and defining two variables, each with the var statement, as a comma separated list. The line break is not significant. So instead of writing var a = 1; var b = 2; i wrote var a = 1, b = 2; which is equivalent to the prior statement. It's a bit more concise but arguably a bit less clear, so it's a matter of taste and the context you are writing in.

Comment: Okay, great. Thanks. I didn't know that was an workable way to declare variables. Good to know. I am accepting your answer and will follow up with another answer for my use case when I get it right.

Comment: posted another answer below. Still working on it, but if you have any insights, would help me and others who need to apply a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a follow up to the conversation with @jeremy above, adapting a nested array approach to individual documents.

It is not currently working, but by posting it here, I hope to be able to gain insight, get it working and offer another solution.

Right now, the sorting order is not changing when an item is dragged and dropped. If you can see why, let me know or you can also edit the answer:

Add id to li:

```
chapterId: function() {
  return Chapters.findOne(this._id)._id
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="item headroom-20" id="{{chapterId}}">
```

Sortable JS:

```
Template.chaptersList.rendered = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.$("ol.items").sortable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "ol.items",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    update: function(event, ui){
      var items = $(".items").find("li");
      var publishedChaptersCount = items.length;
      var sortedIds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < publishedChaptersCount; i++) {
        var obj = $(items[i]).attr('id');
        sortedIds.push(obj);
      }

      self.$('ol.items').sortable('cancel');

      Meteor.call(
        "chapterOrderUpdate",
        sortedIds,
        function(error, result){}
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Meteor Method:

```
Meteor.methods({

  chapterOrderUpdate: function(sortedIds){
    var publishedChaptersCount = sortedIds.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < publishedChaptersCount; i++) {
      var chapterId = sortedIds[i];
      Chapters.update({_id: chapterId}, { $set: { order: i+1 } })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think I see an issue Brian - when you call .attr('id') on items[i] it returns the id as a string. you are then trying to push the ._id property of that string (which is undefined) to the array. so the sortedIds array you are sending to the server looks like [undefined, undefined, . . . undefined]. see if it works just pushing the string

Comment: Also you should define var sortedIds = [] outside the for loop and then push to it inside the loop as you are doing

Comment: That works. Thanks! Hopefully this will help others as well. I appreciate your help. Editing to reflect the changes now. Woohoo!